# How to convert String value of xml file into integer

Tags: java, xml

i have a java code which parse xml file to get the id of the topic, i want to convert this String into integer, i have used BigInteger but it does not work:

```
    public void topicid(){
        File inputFile = new File("D:\\Topic.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {   
             DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

             System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
             NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("top");

             for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
             System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
             System.out.println("\n La requete :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           String idtopic=eElement.getElementsByTagName("querytweettime").item(0).getTextContent();
           System.out.println("l'id de la requete est:" + idtopic);
          BigInteger idq= new BigInteger(idtopic);

   System.out.println("l'id final de topic :" +idq);

}
```

Comment: So, you want an integer,or a BigInteger? And what does "it does not work" mean? What is your input, what is your expected output, and what is your actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class has all conversions needed for XML.

For parsing an `int`:

```
int i = DatatypeConverter.parseInt(string);
```

There are other methods for `long`, `short`, `BigInteger`, ...

Comment: i have this output when i have used ,[int i = DatatypeConverter.parseInt(string);]: id 32569981321347074 
id final of  topic is:-1224736766

Comment: @cyli Your value is too big for `int`. You need to use `long i =  DatatypeConverter.parseLong(string);`

Comment: the result is the same "negatif"

Comment: @cyli Are you sure? `long idq = DatatypeConverter.parseLong("32569981321347074");` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `String` to `Integer`, use `Integer` wrapper.

```
Integer.valueOf(my_string);
```

Or, for `BigInteger`, use `BigInteger` wrapper

```
BigInteger.valueOf(my_string);
```

Comment: i have this message [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "] , and my id topic is 34952194402811904 for example

Comment: `eElement.getElementsByTagName("querytweettime").item(0).getTextContent();` return an empty string. Try to print content of parent node.

Comment: the content i print it but the problem i can not convert it to BigInteger (exemple of id= 34952194402811904)

Comment: So instead of Integer wrapper, user BigInteger wrapper : `BigInteger.valueOf(idtopic)`

Answer (score 0):

`idtopic` string may contain invalid characters which cannot be converted to integer.

Can you provide the output of the current code for a more detailed answer?